# Disable MFA for specific app in AzureAD using terraform

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, terraform, multi-factor-authentication

I'm using terraform to register an app in AzureAD, which works fine. I'd like to disable MFA for all users on only this specific app, but couldn't find any option in the [azuread_application](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application) resource that seemed to apply. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you can work with **`conditional access policy`** in terraform like below to `exclude some applications or include only one application.`

> But for that your  account is needed to have role like  `Conditional Access Administrator`, Security Administrator, or Global Administrator
> privileges when `using user principal` or
> `Policy.ReadWrite.ConditionalAccess and Policy.Read.Al`l when you
> authenticated `using service principal`

***`Note: Conditional Access policies are enforced after first-factor authentication is completed.`***

- [***grant_controls***](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/conditional_access_policy#grant_controls) block has `built_in_controls` required by the policy.
  like   *block*, ***mfa***, *approvedApplication, compliantApplication,
  compliantDevice, domainJoinedDevice, passwordChange or
  unknownFutureValue.*
- As [applications block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/conditional_access_policy#applications) supports ***`excluded_applications`***  option
  ,try   to list application IDs that needed to be excluded from the
  policy having mfa in built_in_controls.And ***`included_applications`*** to
  list of application IDs the policy applies to, unless explicitly
  excluded (in excluded_applications). It can be  set to All and  not
  be given  with included_user_actions. Either included_applications
  or included_user_actions must be specified.
- As you don’t want to have MFA for application, exclude that
  application ID and give mfa in built in control.
- Or include that application and exclude all and change the built in
  control to required option you need from available controls.
- And ***`set  included_users  to all`*** as you like to disable MFA
  for all users for that app.

*example:*

```
    resource "azuread_conditional_access_policy" "example" {
      display_name = "example policy"
      state        = "disabled"
    
      conditions {
        client_app_types    = ["all"]
        sign_in_risk_levels = ["medium"]
        user_risk_levels    = ["medium"]
    
        applications {
          included_applications = ["All"]
          excluded_applications = [ ]
        }
    
        devices {
          filter {
           ..
          }
        }
    
        locations {
          included_locations = ["All"]
          excluded_locations = ["AllTrusted"]
        }
    
        platforms {
          included_platforms = ["android"]
          excluded_platforms = ["iOS"]
        }
    
        users {
          included_users = ["All"]
          excluded_users = ["GuestsOrExternalUsers"]
        }
      }
   

 
  grant_controls {
    operator          = "OR"
    built_in_controls = ["mfa"]
  }

  session_controls {
    application_enforced_restrictions_enabled = true
    sign_in_frequency                         = 10
    sign_in_frequency_period                  = "hours"
    cloud_app_security_policy                 = "monitorOnly"
  }
}
```

As you can see in the terraform [Docs overview | hashicorp/azuread | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs):

The left navigation of  document will lists all the methods that can be managed by  Terraform in Azure AD.From that we can notice that it  supports only  some basic things and not all.

**Reference:**  [azuread_conditional_access_policy | Resources | hashicorp/azuread | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/conditional_access_policy#conditions)

Comment: That's a good suggestion (thanks!) It does require a "Azure AD Premium P2" license (I got a trial), and I had to assign new permissions to my terraform principal (did that). Where I got stuck is what values to use in the "exclude_applications" list; I tried referencing `azuread_application.test.id` but get an `"Policy contains invalid applications:   
│ {"dae4e21d-2b36-46f5-b385-4b4efd4f9b7d":"ServicePrincipalNotFound""` error with that.

Comment: Have you tried to create azure ad service principal and then use that appId of that service principal.Also please check if tenantId is given correctly.